# Worklight: Push Notification message length & formatting - limitations

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst, payload

I am facing below issues when sending Push notifications through Worklight.

1. Push Message length is very much limited - around 65 characters
2. payload message when received on device has removed all spacing

like i sent "**This is a test message**" but on device it received as "**Thisisatestmessage**"

Now , what is the limited size of Push message in worklight specially , i know Apple says for 256 Bytes. But what Worklight allows?

and why payload is removing spaces. Even i am sending message from a back-end java service

**My Push Adapter:**

```
function generalNotification(userId, msgTitle, MsgContents, org, logo){
    var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('aahadPushAdapter.GeneralPushSource', userId);
    if (userSubscription==null){
        return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };
    }
    WL.Logger.debug("Sending Push >> userId:: " + userId + ", Message:: " + MsgContents);
    WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, {
        badge: 1,
        sound: "sound.mp3",
        activateButtonLabel: "Read",
        alert: msgTitle,
        payload: {
            msg : MsgContents,o:org,l:logo
        }
    });
    return { result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId };
}
```

my **back-end Java code**:

```
DataAccessService service = WorklightBundles.getInstance().getDataAccessService();
String parm = "['" + userID + "','"+ msgTitle + "','"+ msgContents+ "','"+org + "','"+logo +"']";
ProcedureQName pushMethod = new ProcedureQName("aahadPushAdapter","transNotification");
InvocationResult results = service.invokeProcedure(pushMethod, parm);
jsonObj = results.toJSON();
msg = "Push Sent successfully to " + userID + " " + (String)jsonObj.get("");
```

Please check this code and suggest , if something is missing here?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

1. Does the stripping of spaces also happen in the [Push Notifications sample application provided in the IBM Worklight Getting Started training material](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced)? Because for me, it doesn't.

   If it happens only in your application, need to understand how you're processing the message.
2. As I have mentioned to you in a comment elsewhere, Worklight does not place any restrictions - each PNS (APNS, MSPN, GCM) has its own limitation.

The 256 bytes are not only for the message part of the payload, but for the entirety of the payload, so it could be that for the message part what is left is only 65 characters, but again, this is not in Worklight's control.

I haven't done this yet myself, but you can start stripping the payload and see when it fails, that would be your minimum payload from Worklight's perspective.

The message is not meant to be long in principle.

Another way to maybe increase what you can pass in the message (in the remaining size of the payload)  is to use an alias so that less information is passed, thus more space remains for the message.

Comment: much appreciated if you point out anything missing in my given code above. I am trying for alias too to get more space for message. But for spaces removed, i dont know why its happening, i had taken the same sample code and just extended it. thanks

Answer (score 0):

The stripping of spaces in APNS payload appears to be a defect. I seen the same behavior in my application and was able to reproduce it in the getting started materials. As a workaround I put "_" in the payload as a placeholder for spaces and then removed them in the worklight client.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? If I use the training sample and send a push notification, then in the client app - in the pop-up that shows the notification text, there are spaces.

Comment: @David, did you face the message size issue too? and in which envrionment you are testing, plus WL version, please. Thanks

Comment: I didn't run into the message size issue but didn't test it. I was working with Worklight 5.0.6 on a Mac.